# How can I access textfield of customcell in extension class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have to reach textfield in my extension for update text but I can't call in extension. This textfield part of my custom cell and I use it in table view. I have to reach this textfield in extension and change text. How can I get this?

This code from my tableview I want to change dateTextField text in my extension for picker view.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldCell", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldCell
        let datePicker = UIPickerView()
        datePicker.delegate = self
        cell.dateTextField.inputView = datePicker
        datePicker.backgroundColor = .white
        cell.dateTextField.text = secilenTarih
        return cell
    }
```

Here my picker view extension:

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    secilenTarih = tarihArray[row]
    // In here I want to access dateTextField.
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some of your code?

Comment: @summerfinn3 I add some code I hope its help.

Comment: You don't need to access the text field. Just reload section 2 of your table view after you set `secilenTarih`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the tag to picker and then you can access your cell from the tag and then do whatever you want.

`datePicker.tag = indexpath.row`

and now in picker delegate you can get the cell like this

```
  let path = IndexPath.init(row: pickerView.tag, section: 2)

   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: path)
```

and now you can change the value in the textfield like this

```
cell.dateTextField.text = "your value"
```

Comment: Its worked! Thanks. But in `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: path) ` I add as? myCustomCell.

Comment: @swifty2 yes you should type cast your cell as custom cell

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in different ways. But I believe the neat way would be creating a custom picker and give a reference of your textfield to it.

This could be done something like

```
class CustomPicker: UIPickerView {
var pickerHost: UITextField?
required init(textField: UITextField?) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    showsSelectionIndicator = true
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.pickerHost = textField

    delegate = self
    dataSource = self

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func dismiss() {
    endEditing(true)
}
```

}

```
extension CustomPicker: UIPickerViewDelegate {
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    pickerHost?.text = "set your text here"
}
```

}

Hope this works for you.